# How describe const pointer to an array in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, syntax

I know the type which is pointer to an `int[10] (ptr->int[10])` is `int (*var)[10]`,
but how to describe those of type blow?

the type which is pointer to the `const int[10] (ptr->const int[10])`

the type which is `const` pointer to the `int[10]` `(const ptr->int[10])`

the type which is `const` pointer to the `const int[10] (const ptr->const int[10])`

Comment: Use typedef. Problem solved.

Comment: what is type blow?  is it defined somewhere? :p

Comment: @thang type blow is something you get in C++ compiler errors when you make a mistake in template code.

Comment: oh, well, that blows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int (*ptr1)[10] = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);             // Pointer to int[10]
const int (*ptr2)[10] = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);       // Pointer to const int[10]
int (* const ptr3)[10] = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);      // const Pointer to int[10]
const int (* const ptr4)[10] = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);// const Pointer to const int[10]

*ptr1[0] = 10; // OK.
*ptr2[0] = 10; // Not OK.
*ptr3[0] = 10; // OK.
*ptr4[0] = 10; // Not OK.

ptr1 = realloc(ptr1, sizeof(int)*10); // OK.
ptr2 = realloc(ptr2, sizeof(int)*10); // OK.
ptr3 = realloc(ptr3, sizeof(int)*10); // Not OK.
ptr4 = realloc(ptr4, sizeof(int)*10); // Not OK.
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the variable as you do:

```
const int somevar[10];
```

Now replace variable name with new typename and prepend the word typedef.

```
typedef const int ci10_type[10];
```

Now `ci10_type` is the type of `const int [10]`

You can do similar for more complex types also as long as you know how to declare those. (Functions as well as data)

```
typedef const int *cpi10_type[10];
typedef const int (*pci10_type)[10];
```

For pointer to these types you can use:

```
ci10_type *pci10var;
```